# Change ActiveX Treeview Node Back colour

Tags: vbscript, treeview, activex

I am trying to change an ActiveX TreeView Node Background colour, using VBScript.  I thought it would be as easy as this: `Node.BackColor = vbBlue` But clearly it is not.  I am struggling to find documentation on this control.

This is my code so far:

```
Set Node = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("T" & CStr(ParentNodeID),4,"T" & CStr(NewNodeID),NodeText,CInt(ImageNumber),CInt(SelectedImageNumber))
Node.Tag = Tag
Node.BackColor = vbBlue
```

This is the error I am getting when running this code:
[image: Error Message]

Not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful documentation on this control here [The Treeview ActiveX control - the basics](https://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=576).  And my code would have worked, only with a newer version of the control.  I had an older version and that was my only problem.  I used `Microsoft TreeView Control 6.0`, and my older version was `Microsoft TreeView Control 5.0`.